# Replace XML Node with Array of Nodes using java

Tags: java, xml

How can I replace a Node with Array of Nodes?

I tried:

```
specialNode.getParentNode().replaceChild(newNode[i], specialNode);
```

For example:
**Input:** `PathToXMLFile` and `SpecialKeys[] = {"value-2","value-3","value-4"}`

```
<root>
    <childOne>
        <otherNode />
        <otherNode />
        <specialNode key="value-1">
        </specialNode>
        <otherNode />
    </childOne>
    <childTwo>
    </childTwo>
</root>
```

**Required output:**

```
<root>
    <childOne>
        <otherNode />
        <otherNode />
        <specialNode key="value-2">
        </specialNode>
        <specialNode key="value-3">
        </specialNode>
        <specialNode key="value-4">
        </specialNode>
        <otherNode />
     </childOne>
     <childTwo>
     </childTwo>
</root>
```

- **Note:** I need to maintain order of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to do either

- insert new nodes at and delete old node (or)
- replace the parent itself, ie. construct ChildOne with new content of
  children nodes and replace

Comment: How can i insert nodes at specific location?

Comment: Found my solution at, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247577/how-can-i-insert-element-into-xml-after-before-certain-element-in-java

Thanks,