# Modify existing XML, adding and deleting nodes java

Tags: java, xml, dom

Existing XML

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01">
     <OperationRequest>
           <Arguments>xyz</Arguments>
     </OperationRequest>
     <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>123<ItemId>
            <CustomerReviews>
                  <IFrameURL>someurl</IFrameURL>
                  <HasReviews>true</HasReviews>
            </CustomerReviews>
            <EditorialReviews>
                  <Content>text</Content>
            </EditorialReviews>  
        <Item>
     </Items>
```

Need to convert it to

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01">
     <OperationRequest>
           <Arguments>xyz</Arguments>
     </OperationRequest>
     <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>123<ItemId>
            <CustomerReviews>
                  <CustomerReview>
                         <ReviewText>abc<ReviewText>
                         <ReviewDate>May 24, 2015<ReviewDate>
                  </CustomerReview>
                  <CustomerReview>
                         <ReviewText>def<ReviewText>
                         <ReviewDate>June 24, 2014<ReviewDate>
                  </CustomerReview>
                  <HasReviews>true</HasReviews>
            </CustomerReviews>
            <EditorialReviews>
                  <Content>text</Content>
            </EditorialReviews>  
        <Item>
     </Items>
```

I am able to remove IFrameURL and able to insert node CustomerReview before HasReviews, but how can I add more nodes inside CustomerReview. 
Here is what I have achieved till now using other [Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247577/how-can-i-insert-element-into-xml-after-before-certain-element-in-java).

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01">
     <OperationRequest>
           <Arguments>xyz</Arguments>
     </OperationRequest>
     <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>123<ItemId>
            <CustomerReviews>
                  <CustomerReview>hello</CustomerReview>
                  <CustomerReview>hello</CustomerReview>
                  <CustomerReview>hello</CustomerReview>
                  <HasReviews>true</HasReviews>
            </CustomerReviews>
            <EditorialReviews>
                  <Content>text</Content>
            </EditorialReviews>  
        <Item>
     </Items>
```

PS: XML structure have /ItemLookupResponse at the end, but not visible in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a whole day, I figured it out.

Here is the link [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_add.asp), I used to get the work done. The minor difference is, use item(index) function to access particular array position. For e.g. The third line in the below code can be replaced with `x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book").item(0);` while using DOM java.

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
newel=xmlDoc.createElement("edition");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0];
x.appendChild(newel);
```

Same goes for other functionalities.